# Before third element add image using :before

Tags: html, css

I want add image using before elemt to the third li only. I want to hide AWS Marketplace and i want add image there.
To that span already add after class , using before i want add image

```
 <ul class="vc_tta-tabs-list">
    <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#1558949632107-3ba56c03-250e" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Case Studies</span></a></li>
    <li class="vc_tta-tab" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#1558949632107-3ba56c03-250d" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">Blogs</span></a></li>
    <li class="vc_tta-tab vc_active" data-vc-tab=""><a href="#1615875372006-f9d0c991-1ae6" data-vc-tabs="" data-vc-container=".vc_tta"><span class="vc_tta-title-text">AWS Marketplace</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

I am using below code but image not display only third li span only hide

```
#header_bar .vc_tta-tabs .vc_tta-tab:nth-child(3)>a span{
    display:none;
}
#header_bar .vc_tta-tabs .vc_tta-tab:nth-child(3)>a span:before{
/*     content:"vbvbvvbbvbvbnbnbnbnbnbnbnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn"; */
content: url(abc.com11/2-dev/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/15190223/abc.png);

}
```

Comment: You can not display a `::before` pseudo element, if you hide the element itself via `display: none`. These pseudo elements behave as if they were an actual child node inserted into the element.

Comment: Hide the span, and apply the pseudo element to its parent `a` instead maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `display:none`, you can make the text transparent in the list element.
Try:

```
#header_bar .vc_tta-tabs .vc_tta-tab:nth-child(3)>a span{
    color:transparent;
}
```